# How to solve general protection error about so file

Tags: python, shared-libraries

When I run a system service which using python executable file, I got this error:

```
kernel: traps: has[11594] general protection ip:7f07ebf20d49 sp:7f07d27921e0 error:0 in libpython3.6m.so.1.0[7f07ebe2b000+28d000]
```

And the service started failed because of that.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The python executable file is packed by pyinstaller on CentOS7.6, when I use it on another operation system like CentOS7.4, I got this error. But I don't know why and how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I solve this problem?

You can't (at least not with the info you provided) -- all we know is that there is a `SIGSEGV` due to a bad pointer somewhere in `libpython3.6m.so.1.0`.

You would need to run this service under debugger, find out *where* the crash is happening, and then *maybe* you'll be able to find a solution.

> The python executable file is packed by pyinstaller on CentOS7.6, when I use it on another operation system like CentOS7.4, I got this error.

Don't do *that*. Unix systems never guarantee "build on newer, run on older" compatibility.

You need to build your service on a system that is *not newer* than the one you are going to run it on.

Comment: When I use the executable file on a different CentOS7.6, which has a different system chip, I got kernel segfault about the file libpython3.6m.so.1.0,  but on the first CentOS7.6 I test the executable file, it works just fine. I guess system chip may cause the difference,  is that possible?

Comment: @HoLo-Debris A processor may not support the same instructions (e.g. the newer system may have `AVX2`, but the older system may not). But that usually results in `SIGILL`, not `general protection fault`.

Comment: I used C++ dynamic library, which is a .so file,in the executable file. If I don't use it, the executable file works just fine, but when I use it, I may get kernal traps or kernel segfault error. This may be where the problem is.

Comment: I looked up into the core file with GDB, then I found that the program core dumped in the function subtype_dealloc. I added a object in Python, which may use the so file compiled by C++.